# Compatibility Mode Issue Between Win App vs Web App

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, windows, vba

Here is my issue: I have a windows application kinda of old  that I already converted most of it to Web application that works on every browser. 
The web application is missing one part from the windows application that I didn't converted yet ,now here the problem: sometimes the end user need to use the the windows application because the web application is missing the last part that I mentioned, in order to display it on IE the user need to changed the compatibility mode every time. Is there any thing that I can do in order to solve that problem instead making the end user change his compatibility mode every time he switching between that win app to web app in the browser?????!?!?

Comment: How are you displaying a windows application in a browser?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [X-UA-Compatible](https://frankcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/a-guide-to-ie-compatibility-view-and-x-ua-compatible/), usually placed as a meta tag the first child in the `<head>` section. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">` will force IE into IE7 compatibility mode, for example.

Comment: I have it on the web application I put it in the Master Page       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>  but  should I need to put it in the Win Application? if so how and where?

Comment: I'll repeat my previous question -- how are you managing to run a Windows application inside a browser window?

Comment: **How** is what you are not answering.  I know of no mechanism that allows you to run a VB6 app inside of IE.  ActiveX, Silverlight, Java, yes...but not a desktop app like VB6.